# How to add line numbers using Highliter.js in code view Swift

Tags: ios, swift, highlight.js

I m creating code detector using follwing library 
https://github.com/Meniny/HighlightJS.swift

But its not with line numbers. Their is one library available which can be integrated with highlight.js https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/ I m struggling to integrate it with Highlighter.js but no luck

bellow is the code snippet

```
jsContext = JSContext()
jsContext.evaluateScript("var window = {};")
bundle = Bundle(for: Highlightr.self)

guard let hgPath = bundle.path(forResource: "highlight.min", ofType: "js") else
{
    return nil
}

guard let ngPath = bundle.path(forResource: "highlightjs-line-numbers.min", ofType: "js") else
{
    return nil
}

let hgJs = try! String.init(contentsOfFile: hgPath)
let ngJs = try! String.init(contentsOfFile: ngPath)
var value = jsContext.evaluateScript(hgJs)
value = jsContext.evaluateScript(ngJs)
if !(value?.toBool())!
{
    return nil
}



guard setTheme(to: "pojoaque") else
{
    return nil
}
```

Can anyone help me in this, Thanks

Comment: What is the actual issue? getting any errors when inspecting via the safari develop menu? is it not loading anything, or just not showing any line numbers?

Comment: Are you calling the init functions as explained in the documentation? `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` and `hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();`

Comment: @Scriptable No, that only I need to figure out. Actually app is getting crashed with the above code snippet when the highlight method is called